# Access RavenDb server outside

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

By default RavenDb server is run as locahost:port. I need to make RavenDb server "visible" from my frontend server (only from my frontend server). What is the easiest way to achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried to access it? Did you get any error on connection? or Do you want to know how to limit access to database only to your fronend server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access to RavenDb requires an IP address and a Port.

by default, it's the IP address of the machine the service is running on and the default starting port, which is 8080.

Therefore, there's no reason why you can use the Private IP of the machine, instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

At the same time, you can also use your PUBLIC IP to access it. Just make sure you have [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) setup if you're outside your network and you're trying to access the private computer within your network.

First up, find your IP Address. Try going to [one](http://www.whatismyip.com/) of [these](http://whatismyipaddress.com/) [websites](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) which should tell it.

Next, turn on NAT inside your router/modem. This is the hard part. [So try reading the instructions to doing that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QluUPzNuOZQ). If you are really stuck, reply with a comment here, giving your Modem/Router model number.

Lastly, this is all a networking issue. It has nothing to do with RavenDb, unfortunately. :) Therefore, this should probably be moved to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

RavenDB uses RESTful based architecture, which means accessing resources through their identifiers, like URI.

```
http://localhost:8080/ravendb 
is the same as
http://127.0.0.1:8080/ravendb
is the same as
http://[External IP address of your machine]:8080/ravendb
```

Just make sure your external IP address is visible from the *outside*